# How to get Xcode to create a Mac only Target Library

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I was creating a library for our project within a workspace. I got it compiling and running on Mac and I moved on to our iOS version. I created a new target for the iOS version of the library. Once I came back to the Mac version, it had switched to iOS and now is somehow jammed in a way that does not allow me to make a Mac only version of the library:

[image]

Under the Target, it does not allow the iPad and iOS version to be deselected. I also noticed that user the project settings, the deployment target no longer shows a Mac target. How do I unravel this mess and get rid of the iOS issues?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
You must change the Base SDK to MacOS under the build settings

[image]